# USA - can police be criminally charged with false imprisonment for a retaliatory arrest?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, police, qualified-immunity

For example, say a police officer arrests someone for giving them the finger. As I understand it this action is protected under the first amendment.

Can any criminal charges be brought against an officer that does this?

Comment: Just commenting to say that "giving [a cop] the finger" is not an arrestable offense. Neither is cursing at an officer. Provided you have not drawn the officers attention in order to do so. Otherwise it would be considered distracting a police officer, which can more problematic for your immediate freedoms. If they're already looking at you, it is protected expression to flip them the  bird. But you cannot say, "Hey! Officer!" and then do so, and/or follow it with, say, "[fornicate] you!" However this does not mean they won't decide to perform a 'randon stop'.... So....YMMV.

Comment: @TankR. two questions: first, in what jurisdictions is distracting a police officer an offense?  I am unfamiliar with it.  Second, wouldn't one element of such an offense be distracting the police officer _from some official business_ and _for some frivolous or malicious purpose_?  Otherwise it would also be illegal to say to an officer who is standing on the corner watching the world go by, "help, someone's just stolen my wallet!"

Comment: @TankR. .... Distracting a police officer is a lot more involved then yelling 'hey officer' and giving them the bird... Pretty sure that is still covered under freedom of speech. Distracting an officer is probably more on the lines of pretending to be a drunk driver when you leave a bar so that everyone who is toasted can escape unnoticed...

Comment: @TankR. Cursing at a police officer can be an arrestible offense if those words rise to the level of "fighting words".

Comment: Although the question is about the USA, some readers might benefit from being warned that you *can* be arrested, charged, trialed, and briefly jailed for giving a cop the finger or cursing at one in some countries, even developed countries.

Comment: As user253751 says you can, and here in the UK I have been arrested… not for giving them the finger but for telling two cops to f-out of the privacy of my home!

Traditionally, behaviour likely to cause a breach of the peace has been arrestable; has needed to be in the street or a public building; even in public 'fingering' the fuzz could hardly qualify by itself. That broadly meant if I directly threatened you or your crew.

Recent legal changes bump that way beyond anything direct, as is to be explained in the next episode.

More…

Comment: Further…

Recent changes criminalize anything said or done within the hearing or sight of a person likely to be caused harassment, alarm, or distress.

Once when I crashed into your car and you leapt out, jumping up and down, scream and perhaps waving a tyre iron, that might have been a nuisance to the passing public but broadly, it would have been between us.

Today's law suggests you may not do that not because I might mind, but because a little old lady, a small child or any other by-stander might be alarmed.

Who defines 'likely to be' and how 'free' are we?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes.

Examples of officers charged with false imprisonment for making an arrest without a valid legal basis to do so can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0u646nUWfyI), [here](https://www.justice.gov/opa/pr/police-officer-convicted-wrongful-arrest), and [here](https://www.nbcmiami.com/news/local/ex-aventura-police-officer-found-guilty-in-false-imprisonment-and-assault-case/3182579/) (the exact name of the criminal offense varies somewhat between the federal criminal justice system and the various respective state criminal justice systems).

In general, police do not have immunity from criminal charges if they can be proven, and the legal protection that law enforcement officers enjoy when making an arrest apply only to arrests that was lawful or that a law enforcement officer reasonably believed was lawful.

As a practical matter, it is rare for police officers to be charged with false imprisonment criminally, and much more common for a civil lawsuit under 42 U.S.C. § 1983 to be brought against an officer by the victim of the wrongful arrest (see, e.g., [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aey_CQQhAlQ)).

But no legal doctrine prohibits the criminal charge if the officer knew that the arrest was unlawful.

Comment: "As a practical matter, it is rare for police officers to be charged with false imprisonment criminally" But why is this? We have bodycameras now. There's overwhelming evidence. Seems to me like a lot of these cases would be easy to prosecute. Is it just that prosecutors will not prosecute police officers?

Comment: @AmeetSharma Because district attorneys rely on police to support them in bringing criminal cases against defendants who are not police officers. Charging a police officer with a crime undermines the relationship between the District Attorney and the entire law enforcement community (usually one self-organized by a police officer's union). Likewise, police officers tend to not want to work up criminal cases against other police officers. Unless a case is so shocking that even other police officers will not have sympathy for their fellow officer, it is very hard to prosecute these cases.

Comment: @AmeetSharma along with the other answer, you have to realize a police officer is exactly like a deputy DA attorney, and both of them are exactly like a judge, or bailiff, and you, and me. ie, we're all just people. Our vocations should not dictate how much integrity and/or honor we conduct ourselves with. Unfortunately, the world is not perfect. People are different. Some behaviors seen as problematic, particularly without context, can be corrected or at the very least curtailed. And that is all without approaching the fact that socially kind looks after kind. It is a complex tapestry...

Comment: @AmeetSharma "We have bodycameras now. There's overwhelming evidence": look at some trials with video evidence to see how uncertain such evidence can be.  First, video has little to say about an officer's state of mind, that is, what the officer knew or thought about the law or the facts, with respect to whether the officer believed that the arrest was lawful or whether that belief was reasonable.  Second, people can even disagree about the events depicted in a video, for example whether a blurry object is or resembles a gun or knife.

Comment: @ohwilleke But wouldn't a DA NOT charging a police officers undermine the relationship of the Defense Attorney with the people it defends from such infractions? I suppose the DA makes a bet that the people, through the laws they set through representatives, don't actually mean it when they say that nobody is above the law. Almost each and every time the DA wins this bet, but ultimately the outcome depends entirely on the people.

Comment: @Andrei DA stands for "District Attorney" and is another way of saying the prosecutor's office. Criminal defense attorneys represent people charged with crimes and they have a relationship with the police and with the DA that is adversarial.

Comment: @Andrei No it does not. To think that it does is super idealistic. That's just how corrupt the system is. The defense attorneys see the prosecuting attorneys far more often than the one-off clients they are assigned to defend to the point they know each other and work together. They are not opponents. You often hear about how defense attorneys cooperating with the prosecution pressure their clients into accepting pleas for crimes they did not commit.

Comment: @phoog Police BC seem to malfunction at the most odd of times. Also,they can turn the body camera off at any time. While suspicious, that coupled with the fact prosecutors, police, and (sometimes) judges think they are part of the same team makes charges of spoliation of evidence even harder to press.

Comment: @DKNguyen: Defense attorneys advise their clients to accept plea bargains, because of the [trial penalty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_penalty), not because they are lazy or in cahoots with the prosecutor. A defense attorney who does not zealously represent the interests of their client is committing a serious act of professional misconduct, and the verdict may also be challenged under the Sixth Amendment.

Comment: @Kevin You'd hope so right? Well you should read more of the news.

Comment: @DKNguyen: I'm very familiar with the problem of false arrests, false confessions, false convictions, etc. What I'm saying is that the defense attorney is seldom the cause, not that the problem does not exist.

Comment: @ohwilleke I knew already what a District Attorney is, but thanks. The prosecutor defends the people from criminals. That's its role. If a police officer happens to also be a criminal and the District Attorney is not prosecuting, then it doesn't do its job as assigned by its boss, which is the District, more specifically, the people of the district.